# Changing the 'src' attribute of an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I'm using javascript, so that when a refresh button is clicked it begins to spin around until the refresh is completed. This is my function:

```
function RefreshHome() {

// Refreshes the home page via the image link.

// Make the refresh link animate.
var refresh = document.getElementById("refresh_button");
refresh.src = "images/refresh_animated.gif";

// Refresh the page.
window.location = "home.aspx";

return false;
}
```

This worked perfectly for a while then, as far as I can see, inexplicably stopped working! When the refresh button is clicked on now, the image just disappears.

Does anybody know why this might happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to mention that this would be much easier in jQuery. You wouldn't need to worry so much about maintaining browser compatibility etc. either. As your project grows your code may become unwieldily, so even if you don't decide to use jQuery you should find a [suitable framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) for your needs.

```
var refresh = $("#refresh_button");
refresh.attr("src", "images/refresh_animated.gif");
```

Also be aware that an image that has no src shows up with a placeholder X on most browsers, and you can hide it with `display:none;` or using the `refresh.hide()` and `refresh.show()` methods in jQuery as needed.

Comment: Thanks - at the time of writing that function the site wasn't using jQuery, but we've since added it, and finding it great, old habits just die hard I suppose and I keep writing document.getElementById without thinking!

Comment: I had an aversion to learning it because I didn't see the point, but it's very useful and dead easy if you're comfortable with pure js

Comment: Also - it doesn't show up with an X as before it's clicked, the src attribute is "images/refresh_stationary.png"

Comment: ah great, that'll work great too. I also found `addClass` and `removeClass` useful for adding styling cleanly to elements.